# numpy.random.randint does not return a list separte by comma

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am running this code:

```
import numpy as np
Z=np.ones(10)
I = np.random.randint(0,len(Z),20).
print I 

#[9 0 0 1 0 2 3 4 3 3 2 2 7 8 1 9 9 2 1 7]

#so this instruction does not work
print Z[I]
```

return a list without where the elelements does not separates by comma as mentioned here [randint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

Comment: np.random.randomint(0,len(Z),20). is bd syntax.  Maybe np.random.randint(0,len(Z),20) ??

Comment: @DaveX,it was a typo, I mean randint() I edited my code

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Does it give an incorrect answer? Does it generate an error message? Does it produce no output at all? More concretely, what output do you get, and what output do you expect?

Comment: @phdstudent np.random.randint() returns an ndarray, you can get a list by using `list(I)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output on that page shows the interpreter (or `repr`) output. Also, I changed it to randint and removed the period that would have thrown a syntax error.

```
import numpy as np
I = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
print(I) # => [9 4 2 7 6 3 4 5 6 2]
print(repr(I)) # => array([9, 4, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2])
print(type(I)) # => <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
L = list(I)
print(L) # => [9, 4, 2, 7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the randomint to randint works for me:

```
Z=np.arange(10)
I = np.random.randint(0,len(Z),20)
print I 

#[9 0 0 1 0 2 3 4 3 3 2 2 7 8 1 9 9 2 1 7]

#so this instruction works for me 
print Z[I]

# [3 9 6 6 7 7 7 3 7 5 5 2 1 1 5 7 1 0 7 4]
```